# unable to boot from USB flash drive (kubuntu 12.04.3 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, installation, usb-flash-drive

I've downloaded kubuntu 12.04.3 LTS .iso and tried to install it on a flash drive to install the system on my hard drive. I've tried to use usb-creator-kde 3 times and unetbootin once and each time the USB flash drive was omitted by the machine startup - the grub just opened like there was no flash drive plugged. I think that my USB flash drive has the booting ubuntu installed correctly, but I have no proof of that.

I know I had to set up BIOS to read from USB and I did, unfortunately, no effect. This is my BIOS setup:

```
Boot Option #1   USB Hotplug FDD
Boot Option #2   SATA Optiarc DVD RW AD-7560S
Boot Option #3   SATA HITACHI HTS542525K9SA00
Boot Option #4   MBA v10.7.5 Slot 0200
```

I'm using lenovo ideapad Y530.

Is there anything wrong here? Can someone point me on what to do?

Comment: My old Lenovo had an option during boot to show all bootable media, I think it was `F8` (but reference your manual or bios screen).  See if it shows up there, if not - the question becomes if it is your USB your your computer, which can be determined fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you turn off secure boot and fast boot?
- Is it a windows 8 machine? If it is, you have to go into the advanced settings in bios to change the boot mode from UEFI to legacy/CMS. Then it should work if the USB is properly set up to boot.

**HOWEVER, if you do this you may have to go back into bios and change it back to UEFI for windows 8 to be able to boot up again.**